# Are there some practical examples that illustrate pipelining in datapath and control?

Tags: mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

Pipelining in the data path is simply divvying/cutting (theoretically) the resources. But pipelining the control means each resource at piped stages gets the separate control signals?

For instance, in most of the RISC architectures, we have 5 stages of pipelining, and the Mem pipe stage has the separate control signal for load or store?

Are there some practical examples of control pipelining?

Comment: Why is this tagged x86?  x86 pipelines have never been very similar to classic 5-stage RISC.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline).  486 was a scalar pipeline, but still had to handle stuff like `add [edx], eax` memory RMW instructions.   [mips] is a canonical example of a classic RISC, the most widely used for teaching about it these days.

Comment: In textbook risc architectures they teach the classic 5 stage...Doesnt mean that it is limited to risc and does not in any way mean that is how actual processors are designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a classic 5-stage pipeline, each stage of the pipe has inputs that come from the previous stage (except the first one, of course), and each stage of the pipe has outputs that go to the next stage (except the last one, of course).  It stands to reason that these inputs & outputs are comprised of both data and control signals.

The EX stage needs to know what ALU operation to perform (control: ALUOp) and the ALU input operands (data).

The MEM stage needs to know whether to read memory (control: MemRead) or to write memory (control: MemWrite) (plus size & type for extension, usually glossed over) and where to read (data: Address) and what to write (data: Write Data).

The WB stage needs to know whether to write a register (control: RegWrite) and what register to write (data: Write Register) and what value to write to the register (data: Write Data).

In the single stage processor, all these control signals are generate by lookup (using the opcode) in the ID stage.  When the processor is pipelined, either those signals are forwarded from one stage to another, or else, each stage would have to repeat lookup using the opcode (then opcode would need to be forwarded from one stage to another, in order for each stage to repeat the lookup, though it is possible that the opcode is forwarded anyway, perhaps for exceptions).  (I believe that repeating the lookup in each stage would incur costs (time & hardware) as compared with forwarding control signals, especially for WB which is supposed to execute in the first half of a cycle.)

Because the WB stage needs to know whether to write a register, that information (control: RegWrite) must be passed to it from the MEM stage, which gets it from the EX stage, which gets it from the ID stage, where it is generated by lookup of the opcode.  EX & MEM don't use the RegWrite control signal, but must accept it as an input so as to pass it through as output to the next stage.

Similar is true for control signals needed by MEM: MemRead and MemWrite, which are generated in ID, passed from EX to MEM (not used in EX), and MEM need not pass these further, since WB also doesn't use those signals.

Comment: Exact! Thanks, Erik!

Answer (score 2):

If you look in chapter 4 of *Computer Organization and Design RISC-V edition*, towards the end of the chapter (Fig 4.44 in the 1st edition), it shows the control signals output from one stage passing through stage pipeline registers and into the next intermediate stage. For example, Instruction [30, 14-12] is fed into ID/EX and then read by ALU Control in the EX stage. That is an example of pipelining a control signal.

[image]

Comment: (a) This question is tagged MIPS, but your answer goes to RISC V, which is similar but not the same ISA. (b) ALUOp would be a better example of control signal forwarding since that signal comes out of the control unit, whereas Instruction[...] would generally be considered data rather than control (as indicated by its being shown in black, not blue).

Comment: It was originally tagged x86. It really should be re-tagged from MIPS to RISC.

Comment: Ok, I guess we don't really know for sure whether MIPS or RISC V or ARM even, just 5 state pipeline..